# Prove that $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[y]/(y^2)$ as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra.

Tags: ring-theory, quotient-group, algebras

How could I prove that $A=\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2+1)^2$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}[y]/(y^2)$ as a $\mathbb{C}$ algebra? Are there any known isomorphisms or is there a trivial way to do so?
I have been able to identify A as $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 3}$ but don't really know how to construct the isomorphism. Also, does it affect in anything the fact that it is as a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra?

Comment: First you have to tell us how $\mathbb R[x]/(1+x^2)^2$ is a $\mathbb C$-algebra.

Comment: is the second ring meant to be $\mathbb{C}[y]/(y^2)$?

Comment: Please correct the notational typos in your post with the edit button.

Comment: I am trying to explore an isomorphism with the basis $\{1,x,x^2+1,x^3+x\}$ to $\{1,i,y,yi\}$ but the multiplication table fails in $x·x$. I have been thinking for a while and am unable to find any other that is so similar.

Comment: maybe just focus on showing it as an $\Bbb R$-algebra. A priori I don't think there's a canonical way to view $\Bbb R[x]/(f)$ as a $\Bbb C$-algebra

Comment: I did prove it is a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, it's messy but doing $\lambda·(x·y)$, $(\lambda·x)·y$ and $x·(\lambda·y)$ for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$ and showing they're the same does the trick. Don't really think it is that relevant to create the isomorphism though.

Comment: it's completely relevant. You can't ask "are $X$ and $Y$ isomorphic as $\Bbb C$-algebras?" if we don't even know what the $\Bbb C$-algebra structure on $Y$ is

Comment: I used the basis I mentioned in an earlier comment, the $\{1,x,x^2+1,x^3+x\}$ one.